# Android SdCard detection issue

Tags: android, sd-card

I have a board on which Froyo has been ported. Now I would also like it  to support a sd card as well. The card (Canon SDC-32m), while inserting is not being detected at all. But the removal is being detected ie. it shows SD card removed in the alert bar. What is the problem ? While booting up the board, it does show the following in hyperterminal (Unknown partition table). In the log Cat i get the following message
 01-01 00:09:29.822: DEBUG/Vold(877): Volume sdcard state changing 0 (No-Media) -> 2 (Pending)

Answer (score 1):

Probably It's not about your board, your sdcard may be damaged. Try fsck or formatting your sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the Linux kernel inside Froyo was not ported properly, or there may be hardware issues with the board.